# db2pd - db SAMPLE -wlock detail does not show Table and Schema name

Tags: db2, deadlock

db2pd - db SAMPLE -wlock detail does not show Table and Schema name.

Dear Db2 Experts,
Is there a reason why db2pd - db SAMPLE -wlock detail would not show the table and schema name.

We run DB2 Version 10.5 on Windows 2008

[image]

Comment: It works correctly for me. Edit your question to add fixpack detail, and operating-system details for the Db2-server, and show evidence that some table-locks or row-locks exist that are not being reported by `db2pd -db sample -wlock detail`

Comment: db2pd runs unlatched so it's possible the row-locks get released before the details can be fetched. Do you have evidence that specific row-locks are waited-on  for longer than the duration of db2pd ?  You can add the `-repeat 1` to cause db2pd to run the report every second until you control-C it, and then check if any of the reports show the tabschema/tabname. I will also check on my Windows environments if I can recreate your symptom.

Comment: Currently I only have Db2 v11.1.2020 on Windows, and it also works correctly (i.e. the -wlocks detail shows the tabschema and tabname for row locks that persist long enough).   Please double check with the `-repeat 1` additional option, and also report which *fixpack* of Db2 V10.5 you are running on Windows?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the responses. I made a note in my howto documentation about deadlock analysis to run it next time with -repeat 1.
Our deadlock dissapeared now and I cant re-produce it.